# Find a file and delete the parent level dir

Tags: bash, find

How would it possible to delete the parent dir (only one-level above) where the file is located and is found with `find` command like

`find . -type f -name "*.root" -size 1M`

which returns

`./level1/level1_chunk84/file.root`

So, I want to do actually delete recursively the level_chunck84 dir for example..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.root" -size 1M -print0 | \
xargs -0 -n1 -I'{}' bash -c 'fpath={}; rm -r ${fpath%%$(basename {})}'
```

`find` + `xargs` combo is very common. Please refer to `man find` and you will find a few examples showing how to use them together.

All I did here I simply added `-print0` flag to your original find statement:

> -print0
>                True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character (instead of the newline  character  that  -print
>                uses).   This  allows  file  names  that contain newlines or other types of white space to be correctly interpreted by programs that
>                process the find output.  This option corresponds to the -0 option of xargs.

Then piped out everything to `xargs` which serves as a helper to craft further commands:
- execute everything in `bash` subshell
- assign file path to a variable `fpath={}`
- extract `dirname` from your file path

> ${parameter%%word}
>                Remove matching suffix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches  a
>                trailing  portion  of  the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the
>                shortest matching pattern (the `%'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the`%%'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or  *,  the
>                pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is
>                an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array  in  turn,  and  the
>                expansion is the resultant list.

- and finally remove recursively

Also there's a little shorter version of it:

```
find . -type f -name "*.root" -size 1M -print0 | \
xargs -0 -n1 -I'{}' bash -c 'fpath={}; rm -r ${fpath%/*}'
```

Comment: thanks...although I was hoping to have something simpler

Comment: I've added few comments to help you understand what's going on under the bonnet